# Android - How to get Vibrate on ring status?

Tags: android

ICS and JB has a OS setting: "Vibrate on ring". I tried next code try to get the status, but the values  are not the same. Is there Broadcast or other method I could use?

```
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    boolean bVibrateRing = audioManager
            .shouldVibrate(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER);
```

In ICS Sound mode and when check the "Vibrate on ring", it will be true.
But in JB it will be false.

I tried Broadcast like this:

```
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                int nstate = extras
                        .getInt(AudioManager.EXTRA_RINGER_MODE);
                Log.d("receiver", " receiver EXTRA_RINGER_MODE :  "
                        + nstate);
            }
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(
            AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

I could only get next mode change:

```
RINGER_MODE_NORMAL
RINGER_MODE_SILENT
RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE
```

There is no information about  "Vibrate on ring".

Thank you for your any hint and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next code could check the status:

```
Settings.System.getInt(this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                       "vibrate_when_ringing", 0);
```